# How can I get data into a Sails.js app from a MongoDB?

Tags: angularjs, json, sails.js, sails-mongo

I have a Sails.js app that needs to fetch from a Mongo database, then display that data in a graph. Alternately, it can take data from a JSON file located on the server.

I am struggling with that process immensely. What seems like it should be an easy task is anything but. I should mention that I am not terribly familiar with Sails.js, but this is what I was directed to use.

I am seeking either examples, documentation, advice, pointers, alternatives, basically anything that would point me in the right direction.

I realize that this is likely to generate a lot of opinion over the "best" and that's not what I am after. I am looking for direction towards resources or guidance on technique.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

you can read this [link](http://sailsjs.org/documentation/concepts/models-and-orm) to understand how integrate mongodb with sails.js

i will list  logic steps to understand how you can get data

- after install mongodb-sails driver in package.json to open
  connection between sails and mongodb
- you have to define model which  map your mongodb documents to
  Models
- define model attributes
- you can use waterline to get document , findbycolumnname and make
  CRUD operations